# Was the "purple color paper" supposed to go inside Lu Shu instead of Lu Xiaoyu?

Tags: spare-me-great-lord

I'm talking about the *Spare Me, Great Lord* (*Da Wang Rao Ming*) anime with 12 episodes released till now, not the manga.

So, Lu Shu just started activating and developing his powers after met with an accident, and there's this one episode in it where Lu Shu opened another purple color paper like thing after trying the spin wheel. And Lu Xiaoyu was near him and that paper went inside her.

So, was this meant to be gone inside Lu Shu, or was it accidentally went inside Lu Xiaoyu because she was closer to Lu Shu?

Answer (score 1):

**According to Fandom**(novel-based spoilers)
Lu shi shared his power with lu Xiaoyu, they both are reincarnations and she knows about her previous life as well.
[Source link](https://spare-me-great-lord.fandom.com/wiki/Lu_Xiaoyu)

**My personal views**

I completed that anime long ago, and lu shu got awakened when he saw that superhuman with firepower doing a magic show on the street(his locket reacted the first time and he was able to see an awakened person in slow motion) along with his sister but he didn't know it at that time. Later he met with an accident and his power got self-activated and his locket is somewhat related to his awakening. As you can see magic items can make an awakened person more powerful, like ruins items or spirit stones. Even the magic apple he creates has magic abilities like healing her sister's illness. Seems like this item come from another dimension having magic items but I am not sure about that point.

So now finally I come to your answer, that black magic paper went inside Lu Xiaoyu because that nebula map is totally opposite of lu shi nebula map, also lu shi is already awakened person and that nebula map(black paper) has the power of awakening just like lu shi locket.